# Multiple ifs in a stream using filters

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, java-stream

How can we represent the following using streams and filters. Thanks.

```
for (UIDisplayItem uiDisplayItem : uiDisplayItems) {
    if ("8929".equals(uiDisplayItem.getProductSpecCharacteristicID())) {
        type1 = uiDisplayItem.getValue();
    }
    if ("5121".equals(uiDisplayItem.getProductSpecCharacteristicID())) {
        type2 = uiDisplayItem.getValue();
    }
    if ("4981".equals(uiDisplayItem.getProductSpecCharacteristicID())) {
        type3 = uiDisplayItem.getValue();
    }
    if ("501".equals(uiDisplayItem.getProductSpecCharacteristicID())) {
        type4 = uiDisplayItem.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't. Because this is surely part of a much larger chunk of code. Streams and filter aren't a magical wand that beautifies any line of code. You'll need to tell exactly what you want to do here.

Comment: And certainly not a chunk of code like you have here: I can count 4 side-effects already.

Comment: You may use a `switch` statement instead. Though a complete redesign to eliminate the need for such comparison is much more recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "for" with "forEach" and do something like below:

```
list.forEach(item ->
        {
            if ("8929".equals(item.getProductSpecCharacteristicID())) {
                type1 = item.getValue();
            }
            if ("5121".equals(item.getProductSpecCharacteristicID())) {
                type2 = item.getValue();
            }
            if ("4981".equals(item.getProductSpecCharacteristicID())) {
                type3 = item.getValue();
            }
            if ("501".equals(item.getProductSpecCharacteristicID())) {
                type4 = item.getValue();
            }
        });
```